# Why does \nodexn{(1,1)}{A} produce strange N-A.x and N-A.y?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}


\begin{document}
\section*{With pnode}

\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
    \pnode(1,1){A}
    \rput(0,3){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,0){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
\end{pspicture}

\section*{With nodexn}

\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
    \nodexn{(1,1)}{A}
    \rput(0,3){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,0){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

I strongly believe by inspection that `\nodexn` does not respect the existence of `saveNodeCoors` so the variable `N-<node_name>.x` and `N-<node_name>.y` are left uninitialized.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}


\begin{document}
\psLoop{5}{%
\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
    \pnode(1,1){A}
    \rput(0,2){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,1){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
    %
    \nodexn{(1,1)}{B}
    \rput(2,2){\psPrintValue{N-B.x}}
    \rput(2,1){\psPrintValue{N-B.y}}
\end{pspicture}
\qquad}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What I find interesting is that the node generated by `\nodexn` seems to have the correct coordinates, not only in the displayed output, but also when you use `\shownode`.  However, things seem to go awry when you apply `N-<node_name>.x` and `N-<node_name>.y` to a node generated via `\nodexn`

Comment: I've been mucking around with this since you posted similar questions yesterday.  Very bizarre and hard to debug.  Other than `\shownode` do you know of other tools to help see what's happening inside the `ps` part of `pstricks`?

Comment: It is absolutely [a bug](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FRdiW.png)!

Comment: I will give  10 bounties of 500 each to a person who can prove that my assumption (i.e., there is a bug in `\nodexn` causing this issue) is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a bug in `\nodexn`, but could be regarded as a bug in `saveNodeCoors`. You can see the same behaviour when using e.g. `\pnode(1,1){A}\pnode(A){C}`. The error happens also with `\nodexn`, because that macro defines an internal node, which value is loaded in order to save its coordinates in `N-<node>.x` and `N-<node>.y`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,3)
    \pnode(1,1){A}
    \rput(0,2){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,1){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
    %
    \nodexn{(1,1)}{B}
    \rput(2,2){\psPrintValue{N-B.x}}
    \rput(2,1){\psPrintValue{N-B.y}}
    % 
    \pnode(A){C}
    \rput(4,2){\psPrintValue{N-C.x}}
    \rput(4,1){\psPrintValue{N-C.y}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

That happens, because the Postscript transformation matrix when saving `N-<node>.x` and `N-<node>.y` is not the same as the one when saving the new node. And this error appears only when loading the coordinates from a previous node, which happens e.g. with `\pnode(A){C}` or with `\nodexn`, which internally uses a temporary node from which the coordinates are loaded.

The following changes to `\pst@newnode` fixes the error:

Replace the lines

```
\ifPst@saveNodeCoors
    \ifx\relax#3\relax 0 0 \else #3 \tx@UserCoor \fi
```

with

```
\ifPst@saveNodeCoors
    \ifx\relax#3\relax 
      0 0 
    \else 
      gsave 
        tx@Dict begin 
          STV CP T
        end
        #3 \tx@UserCoor
      grestore
    \fi
```

The following example, which has these changes, give the correct results:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\makeatletter
% the following is the definition from pst-node.tex v 1.30, with the mentioned changes
\def\pst@newnode#1#2#3#4{%
\pst@killglue
\leavevmode
\pst@getnode{#1}\pst@thenode
\pst@Verb{
  \ifPst@saveNodeCoors
    \ifx\relax#3\relax 
      0 0 
    \else 
      gsave 
        tx@Dict begin 
          STV CP T
        end
        #3 \tx@UserCoor
      grestore
    \fi 
%  startGlobal
%  \tx@UserCoor
  /N-#1.y\space exch def
  /N-#1.x\space exch def
%  endGlobal
  \fi
  \pst@nodedict
  {#3}
  \ifx\psk@name\relax false \else \psk@name true \fi
  \pst@thenode
  #2
  {#4}
  \tx@NewNode
  end 
}%
%
\global\let\psk@name\relax%
\pstree@nodehook%
\global\let\pstree@nodehook\relax}
\makeatother

\psset{saveNodeCoors}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,3)
    \pnode(1,1){A}
    \rput(0,2){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,1){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
    %
    \nodexn{(1,1)}{B}
    \rput(2,2){\psPrintValue{N-B.x}}
    \rput(2,1){\psPrintValue{N-B.y}}
    % 
    \pnode(A){C}
    \rput(4,2){\psPrintValue{N-C.x}}
    \rput(4,1){\psPrintValue{N-C.y}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

This problem has been fixed in `pst-node.tex`, version `1.32  2014-02-03`.